# MVC razor layout - modify from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

This is my layout page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>       
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "selected"})
    @Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "User")
    @Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "ProductCompany")

    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to modify actionlink "selected" class depending on the loaded view on the server side. I am looking for options available to do it.

Best regards

Comment: First, you should forget ASP.NET WEB FORMS logic...

Comment: Good Point @AliRızaAdıyahşi. Dzenan, use a ViewBag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could send the class name in the `ViewBag` and set it as below;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = @ViewBag.myClass})
```

Comment: Its only one a tag that will be selected. So you suggest to have: 

Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { class = ViewBag.IsHomeSelectedClass})
Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "User", null, new { class = ViewBag.IsUserSelectedClass})

and in me views:
HOME: ViewBag.IsHomeSelectedClass = "selected"

USER: ViewBag.IsUserSelectedClass = "selected"

Best regards

Comment: In your controller action, assign `@ViewBag.myClass = "selected"`. You can use many ViewBag properties for many different classes or you could use a single one for many ActionLinks. Depend on the requirement.